# Understanding a Makefile with $(basename $(notdir $@))

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile

I am trying to understand a Makefile, but I don't understand the recipe line with the comment.

```
...
...
sample.a:
    cd ../$(basename $(notdir $@)) && make    ##i don't understand this
...
...
```

I'm still a newbie at this. Can you give me a very simple explanation about:

> $(basename $(notdir $@))

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you break it down:

`$(notdir $@)` takes away the path from the file name leaving just the file name (so `/x/y/foo.a` becomes `foo.a`)
`$(basename ...)` takes away the extension (so `foo.a` becomes `foo`)

There's a decent reference here: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html

Comment: Excellent answer. Also I use directory name as prefix for `$(notdir $@)`. For example: `@echo "Building source file: " $<
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(OBJECT-DIR)/$(notdir $@)`
And before define `OBJECT-DIR = obj`